# compare specific elements of non-labelled list of lists/matrices python 3.4

Tags: python, list, compare

I have created a long list of lists, from a large data file, that now looks something like this:

```
[[1, -1, 10, 0]]
[[2, 1, 20, 5]]
[[3, 2, 15, 10], [4, 2, 50, 10], [5, 2, 90, 10]]
[[6, 3, 15, 11]]
[[7, 4, 50, 11]]
[[8, 5, 90, 11]]
[[9, 6, 13, 14]]
[[10, 7, 50, 14]]
[[11, 8, 70, 14], [12, 8, 95, 14], [13, 8, 75, 14]].....
```

using this code

```
import csv
import operator
import itertools

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
csv_input = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
headers = next(csv_input)

for k, g in itertools.groupby(csv_input, key=operator.itemgetter(3)):
    row = []
    for entry in g:
        entry = [float(e) for e in entry]
        row.append(entry)
    print(row)
```

Now, I want to compare the 1st value from the first list ([1, -1, 10, 0]), which is 1, with the 2nd value from the first line of the next list, which is also 1. Then, I want to compare the 1st value from first line of the second list, which is 2, with the first line of the next list, the the second line of the next list then the third. And so on...

I know the synax might be awkful, but I was thinking of a code something along the lines of (continued from code above):

```
#save list of lists
with open("matrices.csv", "wb") as d:
    writer = csv.writer(d)

def listCompare():
lists = d
    i=1
    if list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]:
        return True
    else list[i][0] != list[i+1][1]:      #***
        return False
    i+1
    continue
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about this? From looking at other questions similar to mine, most people have variables assigned to each list, is that the only way to do this?

## *** this line is invalid syntax

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: No need for if-else, simply return list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the invalid syntax error is because `else` statements don't take a condition. So in your case you currently have:

```
if list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]:
    return True
else list[i][0] != list[i+1][1]:      #problem line
    return False
```

This should be:

```
if list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]:
    return True
else:      
    return False
```

or if there is another condition you want to check:

```
if list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]:
    return True
elif (condition goes here):
    do something
else:      
    return False
```

But, as @Alexander Trakhimenok said in the comments, you don't even need this if-else statement...

```
return list[i][0] == list[i+1][1]
```

Now, a couple pointers from glancing at your code...

Your function `listCompare` takes no arguments, then you want to make `lists = d` (which I'm guessing is just misindented on the question). You probably want to pass `d` as an argument. Also, list is a bad variable name and I think it might just be a typo of `lists`

Also, I'm not sure why you are using `i` or `continue` because right now (after fixing syntax stuff) your code is equivalent to this:

```
def listCompare(d):
    return d[1][0] == d[2][1]
```